# Computation of the $2n$-th order determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, solution-verification

Compute the determinant of the $2n-\text{th}$ order.

$$\begin{vmatrix}0&0&\ldots&0&3&2&0&\ldots&0&0\\0&0&\ldots&3&0&0&2&\ldots&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\3&0&\ldots&0&0&0&0&\ldots&0&2\\2&0&\ldots&0&0&0&0&\ldots&0&3\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&\ldots&2&0&0&3&\ldots&0&0\\0&0&\ldots&0&2&3&0&\ldots&0&0\end{vmatrix}$$

My attempt:
I noticed the two following blocks:

$\begin{vmatrix}0&0&\ldots&0&3&2&0&\ldots&0&0\\0&0&\ldots&3&0&0&2&\ldots&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\3&0&\ldots&0&0&0&0&\ldots&0&2\end{vmatrix}\;\&\;\begin{vmatrix}2&0&\ldots&0&0&0&0&\ldots&0&3\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&\ldots&2&0&0&3&\ldots&0&0\\0&0&\ldots&0&2&3&0&\ldots&0&0\end{vmatrix}$

I switched the blocks because I was dealing with the determinant of the even-order:
$$\begin{vmatrix}2&0&\ldots&0&0&0&0&\ldots&0&3\\0&2&\ldots&0&0&0&0&\ldots&3&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&\ldots&2&0&0&3&\ldots&0&0\\0&0&\ldots&0&2&3&0&\ldots&0&0\\0&0&\ldots&0&3&2&0&\ldots&0&0\\0&0&\ldots&3&0&0&2&\ldots&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&3&\ldots&0&0&0&0&\ldots&2&0\\3&0&\ldots&0&0&0&0&\ldots&0&2\end{vmatrix}$$
Then I saw we can subtract $j-\text{th column}$ multiplied by $-\frac{3}{2}$ from the $(n-j+1)-\text{column}\;\forall j\in\{1,\ldots,2n\}$

Then I got a $\text{lower-triangular}$ matrix with entries $-\frac{5}{2}$ on the main diagonal.

My final result is: $$D_{2n}=\left(-\frac{5}{2}\right)^{2n}=\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{2n}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: I can't tell what your original matrix looks like. If you have dots between a $0$ and a $3$, are there all zeros between? All $3$s?

Comment: @MorganRodgers, we were told this means the rest of the entries are $0$, so I thought it was the practice in the rest of the world as well.

Comment: When between two zeros, I would assume this. But for example you have diagonal dots between two 2s. I would assume that means it is all 2s between them. So I am unclear about everything.

Comment: If all the entries of the original matrix are integers, then its determinant should certainly be an integer.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, I thought you ask between the entries in one row, yes, the pattern repeats

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya I am telling you that it is difficult to see what the pattern is. Dots should only stretch between two of the same number, when everything in between is also that same number.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, this was on my exam today, so I just wrote it down as it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you switch the two blocks you switch $n$ pairs of rows therefore the determinant comes multiplied by $(-1)^n$.
2. When you perform the column additions only half of the diagonal entries of the matrix are altered.

The final result should be $(-1)^n2^n(-\frac{5}{2})^n=(-1)^{n+1}2^n(\frac{5}{2})^n=(-1)^{n+1}5^n$

Answer (score 1):

A recursion can also be helpful here:

- $n=1$: $D_2 = \begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 \end{vmatrix} = -5$
- For $n >1$, expanding $D_{2n}$ along the first column gives:

$$D_{2n} = 2\cdot D_{2(n-1)}\cdot 2 - 3 \cdot D_{2(n-1)}\cdot 3 = -5D_{2(n-1)}$$

It follows

$$D_{2n} = (-5)^{n}$$